# Find bar index and corresponding data

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am just starting out on pine scripting and I want to find the bar index of the bar which gave highest volume. Now once I have bar index, would like to use the bar index to find other bar data like low and high of this bar index.

```
To summarize
bar_index_needed = ta.highest(volume, 10)//though this give volume value not the index value
bar_high_value= func(bar_index_needed , high)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ta.barssince()` function to count the number of bars since the last time the condition was true.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
bar_index_needed = ta.barssince(volume == ta.highest(volume, 10))
_high = high[bar_index_needed]
_low = low[bar_index_needed]

plot(_high, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles)
plot(_low, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vitruvius, it is very much aligned to my request. Right now it plots for every 10 bars. I only want last 10 bars.